# how to add Legends in bar charts amcharts?

Tags: amcharts

I'm using bar chart(amcharts) in my application and i need to include Legends for that bar charts. so, i added the following scripts for bar script,

```
legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
legend.position = "bottom";
legend.align = "center";
legend.markerType = "square";
legend.valueText = "";
chartx.addLegend(legend);
```

but, the bar chart should show Legends? how do i add legends in my bar chart application.

can anyone give me the solution for this issue asap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the above sample i have edited the sample provided by amchart

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>amCharts examples</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="../amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chart;

            var chartData = [{
                year: 2005,
                income: 23.5
            }, {
                year: 2006,
                income: 26.2
            }, {
                year: 2007,
                income: 30.1
            }, {
                year: 2008,
                income: 29.5
            }, {
                year: 2009,
                income: 24.6
            }];


            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.categoryField = "year";
                // this single line makes the chart a bar chart,
                // try to set it to false - your bars will turn to columns
                chart.rotate = true;
                // the following two lines makes chart 3D
                chart.depth3D = 20;
                chart.angle = 30;

                // AXES
                // Category
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
                categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
                categoryAxis.fillAlpha = 1;
                categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
                categoryAxis.fillColor = "#FAFAFA";

                // value
                var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                valueAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
                valueAxis.title = "Income in millions, USD";
                valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
                chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                // GRAPH
                var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.title = "Income";
                graph.valueField = "income";
                graph.type = "column";
                graph.balloonText = "Income in [[category]]:[[value]]";
                graph.lineAlpha = 0;
                graph.fillColors = "#bf1c25";
                graph.fillAlphas = 1;
                graph.lineThickness = 2;
                graph.bullet = "round";
                chart.addGraph(graph);


                                // LEGEND
                               var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                                legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                                legend.position = "bottom";
                                legend.align = "center";
                                legend.markerType = "square";
                                legend.valueText = "aa";
                chart.addLegend(legend);






                // WRITE
                chart.write("chartdiv");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 500px; height: 600px;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get legend.valueText to appear on a bar chart? Is there another setting?